# Count multiple columns with groupBy - laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I would like to count two columns in a table and group them in one query. My table:

| id | is_correct | question_id | answer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 18 | 67 |
| 2 | 0 | 18 | 67 |
| 4 | 1 | 18 | 68 |
| 2 | 0 | 18 | 67 |

My queries look like this:

```
$questions_ids = array(1, 5, 8, 10, 18, 20);

$count_total_answers =  $this->whereIn('question_id', $questions_ids)
            ->select('question_answer_id',  DB::raw('count(*) as count_answer_id'))
            ->addSelect('question_id')
            ->groupBy(['question_answer_id'])
            ->get()->toArray();

$count_total_questions = $this->whereIn('question_id', $questions_ids)
            ->select('question_id', DB::raw('count(*) as count_question_id'))
            ->groupBy('question_id')
            ->get()->toArray();
```

result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mvhP.png)

I would like to obtain such an array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "question_answer_id" => 67
    "count_answer_id" => 3
    "count_question_id" => 4
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "question_answer_id" => 68
    "count_answer_id" => 1
    "count_question_id" => 4
  ]
]
```

Is this possible in a single query?
Greetings :)